# Ideas for a fitness tagline?

Tags: discussion

SamTheBrandΨ (another CHAOS team member) had the awesome idea to order custom water bottles for the mods and top users on [Bicycles](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/), so I'm stealing it! In order to make this happen, I need a good tagline/slogan that reflects what the fitness site is all about. Share your ideas as answers here, and upvote other answers you like. Winner will also get a free water bottle! Ready, set, go.

PS - see Sam's meta post [here](https://bicycles.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/426/who-wants-water-bottles-who-has-a-catchy-tagline).

Update: I've decided I'm going to hold off on ordering anything until we have a design, since it will be much cooler that way! So keep the ideas coming!

Comment: I'd like some message to help me remind to exercise everyday!

Answer (score 4):

Some random thoughts:

- Survival of the fittest
- Pump it
- Go for it
- Just go for it (as a paraphrase of "Just do it")
- You can do it
- To the MAX (with a picture of some cheesy 80's action hero)
- Just. One. More! (rep)

Comment: +1 survival of the fittest

Comment: If it would be accompanied with an image of some fit person, that could work well

Comment: @Ivo are you volunteering to be the model? :-)

Comment: The "[Ask Ivo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/1317221#1317221)" tagline would go well with the image. :P

Answer (score 4):

Get Answers.  Get Fit.

Making Fitness Personal.

Comment: I like the first one.

Comment: I second that motion.

Answer (score 1):

- Move!
- Get Moving!
- Push yourself!
- Keep going!

Comment: I like someting motivation, though I'm not sure if any of these would fit. I'm almost tempted to just steal 'Just do it'

Comment: I like the "Get Moving!" line.

Answer (score 1):

- Get Fit!
- Strong mind, Strong body
- Exercise for the Mind and Body
- Exercise Your Mind. Exercise Your Body.
- Flex Your Mind
- Work Your Mind. Work Your Body.
- Fitness SE: Where minds and bodies go to get fit
- "[Ask Ivo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/1317221#1317221)" :P

Comment: Strong body, strong mind +1, love this expression.  Though I would have said "Strong body, strong mind."  Thanks how I phrase it in my head when forcing myself to do a set I don't want to do.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this sketch](http://30.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_lqw7qkqqaj1qgthc9o1_500.jpg) - it says "Life is complicated. Sport is simple."  Kind of catchy. But does that seem to imply that you shouldn't have questions about fitness? Could we modify this somehow? Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

How Do Fitness?
(Internet memes are underrepresented in this sample.)

Answer (score 0):

[I just stumbled on Christopher Ickes answer](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/1828/8)
which had a list of 20 motivational fitness quotes. Perhaps one of these fits on a bottle ;-)

http://race-orlando.com/20-top-motivational-fitness-quotes/

Such as: **Eighty percent of success is showing up**